# Anyone know how to get GUID and PID of paths USB in C

Tags: c, windows, get, device, guid

Is there a simple script that will list the attached USB devices by GUID PID etc

Example

```
"\\\\?\\usb#vid_0dca&pid_1054&mi_00#6&9f8cd&0&0000#{80375827-83B8-4A51-B39B-905FEDD4F118}";
```

I cant seem to find how you do this on C and google hasnt been to good.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this can be done with C i looked around before and didnt find an examples think its just visual c++ etc.